# Why does this C++ code compile with some compilers but not others?

Tags: c++

I noticed while working on homework that the compiler on my laptop was a lot more permissive than the compiler on the machine that we're expected to use for submissions. The C++ Compiler on my laptop is `AppleClang 7.0.2.7000181`, and the compiler on the submission box is `g++ 4.9.2`. The code that, in retrospect should not compile, is:

```
#include <iostream>

std::tuple<int, int> foo() {
    return std::make_tuple(1, 1);
}

int main() {
    auto pair = foo();
    int x = std::get<0>(pair);
    int y = std::get<1>(pair);
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also have a CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(foo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -Werror -Werror=sign-compare")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

On my laptop, Clang happily compiles this code and prints out `1,1`. No errors, no warnings, nothing. On the submission box, I'm not so lucky.

```
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp: In function 'std::tuple<int, int> foo()':
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp:3:26: error: return type 'class std::tuple<int, int>' is incomplete
 std::tuple<int, int> foo() {
                          ^
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp:4:12: error: 'make_tuple' is not a member of 'std'
     return std::make_tuple(1, 1);
            ^
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp:8:21: error: 'void pair' has incomplete type
     auto pair = foo();
                     ^
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp:9:13: error: 'get' is not a member of 'std'
     int x = std::get<0>(pair);
             ^
/home/nate/foo/main.cpp:10:13: error: 'get' is not a member of 'std'
     int y = std::get<1>(pair);
             ^
```

These errors make sense, because I'm not including the `tuple` header, but I don't understand why this code compiles at all on my laptop. What's going on here?

Comment: AppleClang's <iostream> header may be indirectly including <tuple> or some other source of the definition of std::tuple. You'd have to look at the headers to know for sure.

Comment: The problem with non-portable code is that it is... well, can you guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different compilers have different header files. The C++ header files are closely associated with the compiler you're using.

What you probably have is that Clang's `<iostream>` itself `#include`s the tuple header files, for whatever reason; hence code that refers to `std::tuple` will compile happily merely by `#include`ing the `<iostream>` header.

Of course, this would be relying on your compiler's specific behavior.

Different compilers have different header files. The C++ standard does not prohibit one header file from automatically including another one; but in order to use a particular class, template, or other resources, the only way to make sure that this class, template, or other resource is available for your code to refer to, would be to explicitly include its header files.

Answer (score 4):

Different implementations may choose to include some headers in other headers. You should always include the headers that you use. If you did that then it would compile with both compilers. It seems that clang includes `<tuple>` in `<iostream>` while gcc does not. They are allowed to do it either way and you have to make sure to include the headers you need.

Comment: It's the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

Standard headers are allowed but not required to include other standard headers. It's likely that clang's `iostream` header includes `tuple` either directly or indirectly. There is no standard mechanism for diagnosing that you forgot a standard header because of this.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that code compiles by a particular compiler does not mandatory mean your code is correct. As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) for `std::tuple` it requires header `<tuple>` to be included, violation of that makes you code incorrect although a compiler is not obligated to detect it and provide diagnostics.