# Does iostream includes functions of cstdio?

Tags: c++

I use Dev C++ 5.11. TDM-GCC 4.8.1

And this code runs well.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
printf("%d\n", 42);
cout << "good";
}
```

But as far as I know, iostream does not include "printf".  (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream)

Why this code run? iostream acutally include printf? Is it a kind of standard?

Comment: Some headers may or may not include other headers. Don't count on it. Include what you need. The above code may break in a different library implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285072/why-does-this-c-code-compile-with-some-compilers-but-not-others/42285125#42285125

Comment: Related: [What should and what shouldn't be in a header file?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167723/what-should-and-what-shouldnt-be-in-a-header-file)

Answer (score 5):

The list of header files included in a system/standard header file is library implementation dependent (that is usually associated with the compiler you're using), and (as far as I remember) the C++ standard does not prohibit one header file from automatically including another one

In your case `<iostream>` is probably also #including `<stdio.h>` (or `<cstdio>`).

Relying on a header file being included in another is non portable to different standard libraries, compilers and platforms, so it's better to make sure that you explicitly #include everything you need.