# Count the vowels of every word

Tags: c++

I have to count the vowels of evey word in a given text. My attempt :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char s[255], *p, x[50][30];
int c;

int main()
{
    cin.get(s, 255);
    cin.get();
    p = strtok(s, "?.,;");
    int n = 0;
    while (p)
    {
        n++;
        strcpy(x[n], p);
        p = strtok(NULL, "?.,;");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(x[i]); j++)
            if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", x[i][j]))
                c++;
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I know that my code is a mix between C and C++, but this is what I am taught in school.

Comment: You code is not a mixture.Actually c++ is the extension to c.There is a backward compatibility between them.

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala That hasn't been the case for decades.

Comment: Are you asking for help fixing an issue with this, or feedback on the code, or something else?

Comment: @molbdnilo But printf() function can be used including #include<iostream> right

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala: printf needs `<cstdio>`, not iostreams

Comment: The issue is that my code counts all the vowels in the text and prints that number instead of counting the vowels of every word and printing that.

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala No, if that works it is entirely accidental. Don't confuse the standard libraries with the languages.

Comment: @Mat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276673/does-iostream-includes-functions-of-cstdio

Comment: `n++; strcpy(x[n],p);` looks wrong to me: I think you want them the other way around, i.e. copy to x[0] and then increase n to 1. (Oh I see you're working around that by using i = 1 to n inclusive.) But it sounds like your problem - you're only getting one output, not one per word? - is that you are not splitting the input into words correctly. Can you debug your program to check how many splits you make, the value of n etc.?

Comment: @Rup thank you very much.I forgot to add the whitespace as a delimiter.

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala: precisely. read the answer carefully.

Comment: To check your code you could always use a debug session.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur indeed, your code works. Whitespaces are not treated as a delimiter, but nothing tells us if this is a bug or a feature (and this certainly explains the unfortunate downvotes). Please, the next time tell us what doesn't work.  The best is to give us the input, the expected result and the wrong result that you obtain.  This would significantly accelerate the analysis.

Comment: Recommendation in general, which in your case would ease the debugging process: break down the code in separate segments. Usually, one would do that with classes, but functions are fine as well. In your case, for example, have there be `string read_input()`, `bool is_vowel(char input)` and `unsigned int count_vowels(string input)`. Big advantage: you can test them separately, resulting in you knowing where the error is located.

Comment: By the way, in most languages [`y` is also a vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y) (and in English when it's not at the beginning of a word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed in the comments.

However, for the fun, I propose you another variant that avoids to use the terrible `strtok()`, doesn't require a risky `strcpy()`, and processes each input character only one.

As you are bound to your teacher's mixed style and apparently are not supposed to use c++ strings yet, I also respected this constraint:

```
const char separators[]=" \t?.,;:"; // I could put them in the code directly
const char vowels[]="aeiouyAEIOUY"; //    but it's for easy maintenance
int vowel_count=0, word_count=0;
bool new_word=true; 
char *p=s;
cout << "Vowels in each word: ";
do  {
    if (*p=='\0' || strchr(separators,*p)) {
        if (!new_word) {   // here, we've reached the end of a word
            word_count++; 
            cout << vowel_count << " ";
            vowel_count = 0; 
            new_word=true; 
        }                 // else it's still a new word since consecutive separators
    } 
    else {               // here we are processing real chars of a word
        new_word=false;   // we have at least on char in our word
        if (strchr(vowels, *p))
            vowel_count++;
    }
} while (*p++);  // It's a do-while so not to repeat the printing at exit of loop
cout << endl<<"Words: "<<word_count<<endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/tBqDGI)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[255];
    int n,i,counter=0;
    cin.get(s,255);
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(s)-1; i++)

        if(s[i]=='a' || s[i]=='e' || s[i]=='i' || s[i]=='o' || s[i]=='u') counter++;

     cout<<counter;
    return 0;
}
```

If you have a vowel( a, e, i, o or u) you are adding up to the counter.
You can also use strchr but this is a more simple, understandable method.

Comment: You can use something like if(s[i]==' ') counter=0 so that every time it is a space betwenn words, the counter resets.

Comment: yes, and handle all the other separators, and use `to_lower()`.  You could also opt for a `switch`, for an easier enumeration of all the cases